# Creating a function which removes an input digit from a bigger number in c

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a function in c with little success.

The function needs to be recursive and accepts 2 ints - a natural number and a single digit in C

The function removes the the input digit from the natural number without shifting it's order.

For example:

if my digit is = 5 and my number is = 512556915

the function will return the number = 12691 , removing all the 5's from it without changing the other digits' order.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code.

Comment: Assuming this is a homework assignment?  You need to show some effort here.  What have you tried? hint - convert the ints to strings, and process them.

Comment: One way would be to convert the natural number to a string, build a new string from the digits of that string which you want to keep, and convert the new string back to an integer value.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  Right now, you need to read about creating and MCVE ([MCVE]).  We'll help you fix problems in an honest attempt to solve the problem; we won't write the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert your `int` into `char*` with the `itoa()` function, remove it all of the '5' digits, and re-convert it into an `int` with the `atoi()` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want recursive function, find the example below.

Which calls the function recursively until number becomes 0 and adds up the reminder.

```
int removeNum(int num, int digit)
{
    if (num == 0) return 0;


    int result = removeNum(num/10,digit);

    if (num%10 != digit)
    result = 10*result + (num%10);

    return result; 

}
```